# Rails SSO implemetation with Ping Federate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

In my Ruby on Rails project I need to implement SAML SSO with Ping Identity as my IDP. The gem I'm using is `devise_saml_authenticatable`

In my `config/initializers/devise.rb` I have:

```
config.saml_route_helper_prefix = 'saml'
  # ==> SAML
  config.saml_create_user = true
  config.saml_update_user = true
  config.saml_default_user_key = :email
  config.saml_session_index_key = :session_index
  config.saml_use_subject = true
  config.idp_entity_id_reader = DeviseSamlAuthenticatable::DefaultIdpEntityIdReader
  config.idp_settings_adapter = nil

  config.saml_configure do |settings|
    settings.assertion_consumer_service_url     = "#{Settings.devise_callback}/users/saml/auth"
    settings.assertion_consumer_service_binding = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    settings.name_identifier_format             = Settings.clientname.sso.name_identifier_format
    settings.issuer                             = "#{Settings.devise_callback}/users/saml/meta_data"
    settings.idp_entity_id                      = Settings.clientname.sso.idp_entity_id
    settings.authn_context                      = ""
    settings.idp_slo_target_url                 = Settings.clientname.sso.idp_slo_target_url
    settings.idp_sso_target_url                 = Settings.clientname.sso.idp_sso_target_url
    settings.idp_cert_fingerprint               = Settings.clientname.sso.idp_cert_fingerprint
    settings.idp_cert_fingerprint_algorithm     = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256'
  end
```

In my `app/models/user.rb` I have

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :recoverable, :timeoutable, :session_limitable, :saml_authenticatable
```

Apart from using my client's IDP, I've set up IDPs using Onelogin and Okta and the above code work perfectly fine.

Unlike Onelogin and Okta, my client's IDP offered by Ping Identity does not first show you the page for entering your email, then another page for enetering your password. In otherwords, no IDP login page like Onelogin and Okta.

So the question is, right now I have the client's IDP's entity id, SSO target URL, SLO target URL, fingerprint. How to I authenticate to the IDP via a form and log user in?

So far I've tried

```
=form_tag(Settings.sso.idp_sso_target_url, html: {role: 'form'}, method: :post) do |f|
    .form-group
      label for="email"  Email
      = email_field_tag :email
    .form-group
      label for="password"  Password
      = password_field_tag :password
      button.btn.btn-info.btn-sm type="submit"  Submit
      | &nbsp;
```

where Settings.sso.idp_sso_target_url is the SSO target url that looks like `https://auth2test.clientname.ca/idp/SSO.saml2`

With Ping as IDP, I got this:

```
<S11:Envelope><S11:Body><S11:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Invalid Request</faultstring></S11:Fault></S11:Body></S11:Envelope>
```

Then I tested using Onelogin as IDP, it just redirected me to the page where I input my email.

I've also tried

```
  = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: saml_user_session_path(resource_name), html: {role: 'form'}) do |f|
    .form-group
      label for="email"  Email
      = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email', id: 'email'
    .form-group
      label for="password"  Password
      = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: 'Password', class: 'form-control', id: 'password'
    button.btn.btn-info.btn-sm type="submit"  Submit
            | &nbsp;
```

This one is giving error Invalid email or password (I'm sure that's correct).

I highly doubt that I'm on the right track. Please point me to the correct direction. Thank you very much!